# Simpler way to break a list of comma separated values into many lists in Python 3

Tags: python, csv, python-3.x, matplotlib

I have a file `codereview_stats.txt` which has data in the following format. The date at the top represents the last date at which data was written in the file and is there for the way I am collecting the data.

```
18-09-2013
dd-mm-yyyy, questions, answers, %answered, users, visitors/day

15-09-2013,9381,15913,88,26972,8466
16-09-2013,9413,15949,88,27015,8466
17-09-2013,9426,15968,88,27041,8871
18-09-2013,9439,15995,88,27082,8934
```

I am using matlotlib to plot the data. But before doing that I need to separate the dates, questions, answers etc. into separate lists. Currently I am doing that in the `get_data()`function as shown below. As you can see there are many list comprehensions here. Is there a simpler way to separate the data into many lists?

```
#! python3
from  matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from datetime import datetime as dt

def get_data():
    with open('codereview_stats.txt') as f:
        data = [line for line in f]

    data = [line[:-1].split(',') for line in data[3:]]

    dates = [dt.strptime(line[0], '%d-%m-%Y') for line in data]
    ques = [int(line[1]) for line in data]
    ans =  [int(line[2]) for line in data]
    perc = [int(line[3]) for line in data]
    users = [int(line[4]) for line in data]
    visits = [int(line[5]) for line in data]

    return dates, ques, ans, perc, users, visits


def show_plot(dates, ques, ans, perc, users, visits):
    plt.plot_date(dates, visits, '.', linestyle = '-')
    plt.grid(True)
    plt.setp(plt.xticks()[1], rotation=30)
    plt.show()


show_plot(*get_data())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`zip()` in conjunction with the `*`](http://docs.python.org/3.2/library/functions.html#zip) operator can be used to unzip a list:

```
>>> strs="""15-09-2013,9381,15913,88,26972,8466
... 16-09-2013,9413,15949,88,27015,8466
... 17-09-2013,9426,15968,88,27041,8871
... 18-09-2013,9439,15995,88,27082,8934"""
>>> lis = [line.rstrip().split(',') for line in strs.splitlines()]
>>> dates, ques, ans, perc, users, visits = zip(*lis)
>>> dates
('15-09-2013', '16-09-2013', '17-09-2013', '18-09-2013')
>>> ques
('9381', '9413', '9426', '9439')
...
```

Answer (score 1):

The stdlib provides the `csv` module to read comma separated files.
And there's the [`DictReader` class](http://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) that does what you want:

> `class csv.DictReader(csvfile, fieldnames=None, restkey=None,
>   restval=None, dialect='excel', *args, **kwds)`
>
> Create an object which operates like a regular reader but maps the information read into a dict whose keys are given by the optional
>   fieldnames parameter. If the fieldnames parameter is omitted, the
>   values in the first row of the csvfile will be used as the fieldnames.
>   If the row read has more fields than the fieldnames sequence, the
>   remaining data is added as a sequence keyed by the value of restkey.
>   If the row read has fewer fields than the fieldnames sequence, the
>   remaining keys take the value of the optional restval parameter. Any
>   other optional or keyword arguments are passed to the underlying
>   reader instance.

Here's how it may look like in your application snippet (untested):

```
import csv

def get_data():
    d = csv.DictReader('codereview_stats.txt',
                       ['dates', 'ques', 'ans', 'perc', 'users', 'visits'])
    return d['dates'], d['ques'], d['ans'], d['perc'], d['users'], d['visits']
```

Personally, I'd change the code to just pass around the dict object `d`.

Your code to type convert the string is still required somewhere. Here's an answer on [how to subclass DictReader to infer types on the columns](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17326597/923794).